# Posting images to Facebook, Twitter & Google+

Tags: facebook

I have a page of thumbnails, which when clicked, open in a lightbox-type overlay to give a bigger image & some text. The overlay has the buttons for sharing on social media & I want to share the specific image & text. The URL can be back to the thumbnail page, but it's the image & really want to show...

The old (simplified) link is:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[Page_URL]" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, 'Share', 'width=700,height=300'); return false;">Facebook</a>
```

But the it doesn't appear to work anymore - there are many StackOverflow questions confirming this.

I've been Googling for a solution, but it seems like you can only share a page - is this correct?

Do I have any options to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: The Feed dialog still allows to specify those values at runtime. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.5

Comment: We're getting a "The specified URL is not owned by the application" message when trying this method...

Comment: The `redirect_uri` must match one of the domains configured in your app settings (so most likely your website URL.)